# ubuntu lockscreen issue

Tags: unity, lightdm, login-screen

When I do <kbd>Super</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> in Ubuntu it locks the screen and original lock screen with white dots appears. Then after 30 seconds the screen goes black and when wake it up again lightdm greeter is shown asking for username and password in middle of screen Currently how it appears:

[image]

Also upon restart lightdm greeter asks the username and password. How can I restore original lock screen with white dots?

Original lock screen appear like this:

[image]

**Edit : ** Also my ubuntu is booting up very slowly. Can someone help me out?

Comment: What changed in between your having the old lockscreen and the current one? Did you install a new desktop environment, install packages, edit configuration files?

Comment: I installed ubuntu mate environment and then removed it. since then I am facing this issue.